# How to make my difference equation make the deadline constraint?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, filter, embedded, digital-filter

Back at it again.

[STM32L43KC Datasheet:](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00151940-stm32l41xxx42xxx43xxx44xxx45xxx46xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

The question this time is I am finally starting to implement my digital filter which can been see as:

Z - Transform:
$$LPF_D=\frac{Y}{U}=\frac{0.3957z^2+0.7914z+0.3957}{z^2+0.3848z+0.1979}$$

Difference Equation:

$$Y_i = 0.3957*U_i + 0.7914*U_{i-i} + 0.3957*U_{i-2} - 0.3848*Y_{i-1} - 0.1979*Y_{i-2}$$

With a sample of \$T_s = \$ 15uS. Created with the Tustin Method. With a Pre-Warp frequency of 20kHz.

Code architecture:

The ADC is sampling at 66kHz.

System clocked at 4MHz

Using a DMA to tunnel the ADC's sample into a short type array that can store up to 2000 samples called:

- "short adcValues[2000]".

I have two interrupts:

1. Triggers when the DMA fills half of the array "The Half Transfer Interrupt"
2. Triggers when the DMA complete the transfer to the array " The Complete Transfer Interrupt"

This allows me to process the top half first while the bottom half is being processed and vice versa.

I have measured the time I am given to be in each interrupt which is 15mS for both the half transfer interrupt and the complete transfer interrupt. So essentially I would need my difference equation to be executed within 15mS.

With the current solution It gets executed in 188mS. I know you can do a lot of things such as used fixed point, DSP, FPU, however I am very new to this and have no idea which approach should I try.

Is my implementation even correct without the optimizations? Is it even possible to execute the code within 15mS when it needs to run 1000 times?

**Code updated:** Thanks to awjlogan. I got the code down to 25mS still not quite < 15mS. I guess the only thing to do is to increase the clock speed?

**Second Update:** Changing the clock speed to 80MHz got the code to 1.1mS! Thank you everyone for helping and giving their input.

```
short adcValue[2048];

uint32_t U_i[3] = {0,0,0};
uint32_t Y_i[3] = {0,0,0};

//16.16 Format
const uint32_t COEFF_0 = 0x654C;
const uint32_t COEFF_1 = 0xCA99;
const uint32_t COEFF_2 = 0x6282;
const uint32_t COEFF_3 = 0x32A9;

    void DMA2_Channel3_IRQHandler(void){

    if (((DMA2->ISR) & (1<<10)) != 0){
        halfTransferComplete = 1;
        DMA2->IFCR |= (1<<10);
    } else if (((DMA2->ISR) & (1<<9)) != 0){
        transferComplete = 1;
        DMA2->IFCR |= (1<<9);
    }
}


   while (1) {
    if (halfTransferComplete == 1){

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++){

         U_i[2] = U_i[1];
         U_i[1] = U_i[0];
         U_i[0] = adcValue[i];
         Y_i[2] = Y_i[1];
         Y_i[1] = Y_i[0];
         Y_i[0] = COEFF_0*U_i[0] + COEFF_1*U_i[1] + COEFF_0*U_i[2] - COEFF_2*Y_i[1] - COEFF_3*Y_i[2];
         DAC1->DHR12R1 = Y_i[0] >> 16;
    }
        halfTransferComplete = 0;

}

    if (transferComplete == 1){

     for (int i = 1024; i < 2048; i++){

         U_i[2] = U_i[1];
         U_i[1] = U_i[0];
         U_i[0] = adcValue[i];
         Y_i[2] = Y_i[1];
         Y_i[1] = Y_i[0];
         Y_i[0] = COEFF_0*U_i[0] + COEFF_1*U_i[1] + COEFF_0*U_i[2] - COEFF_2*Y_i[1] - COEFF_3*Y_i[2];
         DAC1->DHR12R1 = Y_i[0] >> 16;
    }
         transferComplete = 0;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few general suggestions first:

- Recommend using defined types for your declarations, e.g. `uint32_t` rather than `int` for `U_i`. The `u` in `uint32_t` stands for `unsigned`, and I assume you're not using a bipolar ADC. These allow portability across different architectures, as `int` is compiler dependent.
- `short` is also compiler dependent, it's only guaranteed to be *at least* 16bits wide. The natural width for an Arm micro is 32bit, so you might get better performance using `uint32_t adcValue`. Again, compiler dependent, I'm not sure how the M4 handles packing two 16bit values into a single 32bit value.
- Your two loops are identical, so just manipulate the indexing to select between the top and bottom.
- There are often optimisations to be done if you use powers of 2 for the number of iterations. Can you work on `1024` samples rather than `1000`?

To run your loop faster, consider this fixed point approach. Your microcontroller has:

- A 12bit ADC
- A 12bit DAC

We can represent this in something similar `Q12` format (1 integer bit, and 12 fractional), but we'll just normalise things and say `1 > MAX(ADC) >= 0`. This means the integer bit is implicitly zero and we will treat all the bits as fractional. When you do a multiplication of a `Qm` and a `Qn` fixed point, the product is in `Q(m+n)` format; we can handle this later. To convert your floating point coefficients to `Q12` simply multiply them by \$2^{12}\$. Your coefficients therefore map as:

- 0.3957 -> 0x0000_0654
- 0.7914 -> 0x0000_0CA9
- 0.384  -> 0x0000_0624
- 0.1979 -> 0x0000_032A

When you multiply your ADC values with these coefficients, you implicitly get a `Q24` value out. You can do a right shift by 12 to convert this back to `Q12`. Your loop now looks something like this:

```
const uint32_t COEFF_0 = 0x00000654;
const uint32_t COEFF_1 = 0x00000CA9;
const uint32_t COEFF_2 = 0x00000624;
const uint32_t COEFF_3 = 0x0000032A;

for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < 1024; idx++) {
    U_i[2] = U_i[1];
    U_i[1] = U_i[0];
    U_i[0] = adcValues[idx];
    Y_i[2] = Y_i[1];
    Y_i[1] = Y_i[0];
    Y_i[0] = COEFF_0 * U_i[0] + COEFF_1 * U_i[1] + COEFF_0 * U_i[2] - COEFF_2 * Y_i[1] - COEFF_3 * Y_i[2];
    DAC1->DHR12R1 = Y_i[0] >> 12;
}
```

Each iteration through the loop is now (naively estimating) something like 6 assignments and 5 multiply-accumulates (which I believe is a single instruction, `MLA`). As an estimate, let's say 20 instructions per iteration - even at the 4 MHz clock rate you've quoted, that's about 5 ms for 1000 samples. Hope that's helpful!

*Addition*

I've put some code up on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4Fj_DC), you can play with the compiler options there. It produces roughly what I expected, around 35 instructions per iteration. It shuffles things around registers a bit more than necessary, so it would be a good exercise for you to understand that and perhaps tighten it up by writing the assembly. Try changing the compiler options; for example, swapping `-march=armv7-m` for `-mcpu=cortex-m4`.

You said the time is around 25 ms to do all the samples - the accesses to memory and the DAC will slow things down so the rough estimate of time is of the right order of magnitude. I would anticipate that the write to the DAC register takes a relatively long time. Speeding up your clock will certainly make it run faster, and really with something as capable as an M4, you should be running *much* faster than 4 MHz.

Comment: Hey, its gonna take a couple of reads to digest this! But thank you so much for the response. Just a few questions. The uint32_t I understand I read somewhere that 32 bit arithmetic is faster in 32 bit processors cause its supported.I am confused as how 1024 samples works faster than 1000 samples? Just how the compiler will see it? a base of 2? Processor can be maxed out to 80MHz but having troubles switching clock speed not a direct process. Not using the HAL.

Comment: I'll probably put the DAC into another buffer and have a DMA write it to the DAC at the same samples. The biggest concept I dont get is fixed point. I get the whole you can choose your decimal place by multiplying or shifting it for example using an INT if you want a 16.16 then * 2^24. What I am confused about is when you revert it back to the value by shifting it 2^x. How does the code know its a decimal number? isnt it in a INT data type thus let say 0.4132 * 3 = 1.2396 then 1 is going to be in the variable?

Comment: How did you just bit shift a fraction number?

Comment: Every time I tried to bit shift 0.3957<<15 I get 0x32A6.

Comment: @Pllsz In fixed point, the code doesn't know the position of the radix. YOU know. So you shift things to line it up prior to additions and subtractions and you know where it is in the result. For multiplications and divisions, you know where the radix is for both operands so you know where it is in the result. You manually keep track of it and adjust for it. Every. Single. Damn. Time.

Comment: Fair, was just wondering how he got 0x2DF8 for 0.3957 as I get  (0.3957*2^15 = 12966.2976) Store the 12966 in hex you get 32A6

Comment: @Pllsz That's because you're correct. it was a typo. :) I've also changed the answer to something more specific to the microcontroller you're using as well, feel free to check my sums again!

Comment: Things are _usually_ fastest at the processor's native word length. If you force the compiler to use a smaller word, then it will either just zero pad it to the native length, or try and pack multiple into a native length - then it has to unpack (probably back to the native length) to do operations, so more time taken. You can play tricks with this to save storage space, but it will usually come at the expense of (naive) performance.

Comment: Using powers of two is _often_ helpful as there are more optimisations that a compiler or the processor might take advantage of. For example, the buffers in the DMA are almost certainly a power of two depth. Let's say it's 16 - if you want 1000 samples, then it has to do 62.5 transfers to fill the array. The half transfer means it might pad out the empty 8 samples. If you pick 1024 samples, it's just 64 transfers with no waste. When you start needing to scale values, stick to powers of two - it's so much easier!

Comment: @Pllsz Let me know if you have any other questions, I hope that's clearer. (Just noticed your edit, good progress!)

Comment: @awjlogan Thank you again for answering my questions. Appreciate the words! One more question when you say swap values you just mean from int to uint32_t? Also as you read in the post you think clocking the frequency higher would fix my problems? Once again thank you so much

Comment: @Pllsz Ah, no, I just didn't bother typing out the swapping of variables in the `Y_i` and `U_i` arrays. I've edited the code with that, put a link to Compiler Explorer, and commented on the clock.

Comment: @awjlogan Thank you so much for everything, Ill go research ARM GCC flags thank you thank you!

Comment: Haha not exactly sure where to add GCC flag commands in the STM32CubeIDE

Comment: @Pllsz I think STM32CubeIDE is Eclipse based (I've never used it), try Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings (something like that!)

Comment: Ahh, Okay I see. Under the "Tool Settings" Tab in "MCU GCC assembler" there's a command box that says "gcc". I added "gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4" to it, no performance gained

Comment: What I noticed, I just tried uploading the code with Keil IDE instead of STM32Cube and the code got reduced to 17mS from 25mS. I am not sure if Keil IDE already implements the optimized flags such as "-mcpu=cortex-m4" or STM32Cube has very big overhead?

Comment: And maybe perhaps the STM32CUBEIDE generates the makefile with the -mcpu=cortex-m4 flag in it already. I say this because when I take a peak in the make file theres a line that says "$(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"